# "Failed to bind" while loading a kernel extension on macOS 13 Ventura

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, xnu

I try to build and load a basic kernel extension on macOS 13.2 Ventura on M1 (Apple Silicon).

There is a lot of literature online on macOS kext. However, many things have changed in recent versions of macOS regarding kext and most of this literature is obsolete.

Disclaimer: I know that "system extensions" should now be used instead of kext in most cases. In my specific case, this is a test kext to learn more on the Arm64 architexture and my purpose is only to read a few CPU system registers. These registers can be read at EL1 (kernel) only. This is why a system extension is not suitable and a kext is required. BTW, I already did the same thing on Linux with a dedicated loadable kernel module. I now try to transpose this to macOS.

As a prerequisite, I disabled SIP and allowed custom kexts.

I started with the kext template in Xcode and added a few traces, either using `printf()` (several articles on kexts mention a `printf` function in the kernel) or `os_log()`. The build is successful. I copied the kext bundle in another directory and make it owned by root.

When loading the module with `sudo kmutil load -p test-kext.kext`, I get the following errors when using `os_log()`. When using `printf()`, I have the same messages with `_printf` instead of `__os_log_internal`.

```
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=31 "Error occurred while building a collection: 
    1: One or more binaries has an error which prevented linking.  See other errors.
    2: Could not use 'test-kext' because: Failed to bind '__os_log_internal' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __auth_got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbolFailed to bind '__os_log_default' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbol
test-kext specific: 
    1: Failed to bind '__os_log_internal' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __auth_got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbolFailed to bind '__os_log_default' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbol
" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error occurred while building a collection: 
    1: One or more binaries has an error which prevented linking.  See other errors.
    2: Could not use 'test-kext' because: Failed to bind '__os_log_internal' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __auth_got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbolFailed to bind '__os_log_default' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbol
test-kext specific: 
    1: Failed to bind '__os_log_internal' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __auth_got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbolFailed to bind '__os_log_default' in 'test-kext' (at offset 0x0 in __DATA_CONST, __got) as could not find a kext which exports this symbol
```

The Xcode build is successful. In the build log, I see that the link command for the kext uses the options `-no_adhoc_codesign -kext -nostdlib -lkmodc++ -lkmod -lcc_kext`. It seems that some kernel libraries are referenced and I would expect to find the log functions.

In `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform`, I have found `libkmod.a` and `libkmodc++.a` but I could not find any `*cc_kext*`. There is no symbol `*printf*` or  `*os_log*` in `libkmod.a` and `libkmodc++.a`.

How would you log kernel messages from a kext on macOS 13 and how would you build the result?

Comment: `printf` and the `os_log` symbols are all exported from the kernel as part of the libkern KPI. What KPIs are listed in your kext's Info.plist? (If in doubt, include your Info.plist in the question.) Have you run `kextlibs` on your kext? What was its output?

Comment: Thanks. I had to add it in the Info section of Xcode (ending up in Info.plist). Since Xcode automatically added the libraries in the link, I expected it to add them for the runtime bind. My kext works now, including get/setsockopt from user land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libkmod` and `libkmodc++` don't provide access to general kernel APIs; they implement some small stubs of functionality related to kext startup and shutdown code which interact with the boilerplate kext code auto-generated by Xcode, as well as a handful of `OSKext*()` functions.

Kernel APIs are exported to kexts from the core kernel via "KPIs" which have bundle identifiers in the same way that kexts do. So the mechanism for linking against core kernel APIs is the same as declaring a dependency on another kext: the [`OSBundleLibraries` Info.plist property](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/infoplist_keys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009481).

Because identifying which KPI a particular symbol is defined in, there's a tool that scans your kext and spits out a list of bundle identifiers: [`kextlibs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/command_line_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009455-SW5). There is a [man page for `kextlibs`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/kextlibs/) which goes into detail on more advanced uses of the tool.

As established in the comments, missing the requisite *libkern* KPI from `OSBundleLibraries` is what's causing the link errors in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Kextlibs has now been superseded by « kmutils libraries ». I now use it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the various help here, I managed to complete my kext, without Xcode, using only makefiles.

If anyone is interested by a complete kext example for macOS Ventura using makefiles only, you may have a look here:
https://github.com/lelegard/arm-cpusysregs